# Vim hiding quickfix column / gutter

Tags: vim, grep

After running `:vimgrep` I'll get a column to the left that with indicators pointing at lines where things were found. After editing, how can I hide this quickfix column?

Let me know if the question is unclear.
Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319284/vim-sign-column-toggle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That column on the left is the "sign column" and those markers are "signs". You can read about them in `:h signs`.

Both your diagnostic and your solution are completely wrong.

1. Signs are created manually (by you) or programatically (by a script). *Never* automatically (by Vim itself).
2. The sign column appears when signs are created for the current buffer and disappears when there are no signs left.
3. Neither `:vim` nor `:grep` create signs by default and there's no available setting for that.
4. The content of the quickfix list *may* be used to create signs but, like with the commands above, it is not done automatically and there's no setting for that.
5. Conclusion: that sign column and those signs are there only because of a third party script. Find that script, see if this behaviour can be altered with an option and, if not, see if you can change its code or submit an issue to the author.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I had previously encountered the docs about ```signs``` but I thought it wasn't pertinent precisely because the docs were talking about creating signs manually and I assumed it was automatically generated.

Comment: I tried to find which plugin / script was causing this; to confirm what you've said, starting vim with ```-u NONE``` disables sign behavior. Curiously though, when running with a blank ```.vimrc```, however, the behavior persists.

Comment: Try with `--noplugin`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hacky solution: just run `:vimgrep` (or grep) again with a search term that doesn't exist; the gutter column will disappear because nothing is found.

Example: 
`:vimgrep /asdlfjalskdfj/ .`

This is similar to another hack: turning off search highlighting by searching for a nonexistent string!

Answer (score 0):

you can enable and disable the sign column (aka the gutter), check documentation with `:h signcolumn`

First check your current value so you can reset it after temporarily disabling.  Default value is `auto`.

check value with `: set signcolumn` showing `signcolumn=auto`

disable:

```
:set signcolumn=no
```

enable auto:

```
:set signcolumn=auto
```

allowed values for signcolumn are `auto`, `no`, `yes`, and `number`.  Find out more by checking the documentation, `:h signcolumn`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).